# 'Event' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, get, attributes

[Error on 'Event' object has no attribute 'get' ] (https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/error-event-object-has-no-attribute-get/596)

anyone help me please

Comment: Please do *not* post images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you have same name for your view and model(both are `Event`). Try renaming your view to something else(for example `event_view`):

```
#view
def event_view(request):  # method names should be snake_case. Please read pep8 guideline.
    return render(request, 'home/about.html', { 'data': Event.objects.all()})

#url
   path('event/', event_view, name="event')
```

Comment: NameError at /event/
name 'Event' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: 
name 'Event' is not defined

Comment: you need to import Event model, ie `from .models import Event`